# Difference in size of training sample size and test prediction

Tags: r, prediction

I have trained a model on a sample size of 2120x10. Now I'm trying to apply the same model to the test data set and I'm having trouble deriving the confusion matrix.

```
test_predictions <- predict(train_obj, test_data)
test_predictions <- ifelse(test_predictions > 5, 1, 0)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(test_predictions), test_data$outcome, positive="1")
```

I get an error when calculating the confusion matrix as `test_data$outcome` has 2135 values. If I use `test_data$outcome[1:2120]`, everything works fine.

Is there a better way to calculate the confusion matrix without restricting the number of values.? Is it correct to restrict the number of values in `test_data$outcome`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't sound right. How can `test_data$outcome` have 2135 values if `test_data` only has 2120 rows? Even if there are NAs in test_data's predictors, they will be predicted as NA and then ignored by `confusionMatrix`.

```
dat=data.frame(a=rnorm(1000), b=rnorm(1000))
dat=dat %>% 
  mutate(c=5*(a+b)) %>%
  mutate(d=ifelse(c>5, 1, 0))
set.seed(1)
i=sample(1:1000, 750, replace=FALSE)
train_data=dat[i,]
test_data=dat[-i,]
test_data[sample(1:250, 3),1:2]=NA
lr=lm(c ~ a + b, data=train_data)
test_predictions=predict(lr, test_data)
test_predictions=ifelse(test_predictions>5, 1, 0)
confusionMatrix(test_predictions, test_data$d)

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 187   0
         1   0  60
```